# Get the value of arrays in array in twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig, laravel-5.8

I have this array dataPP_ids coming from a controller

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "plan_participate_id " => 47
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "plan_participate_id " => 47
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "plan_participate_id " => 48
  ]
]
```

I just want to show the "plan_participate_id" values in twig file.

I tried

```
{% for details in dataPP_ids %}
<tr>
     <td class="pl-0 align-middle text-center" rowspan="2">{{ details.plan_participate_id }}</td>
     <td>---</td>
</tr>
```

values of details.plan_participate_id are not showing in the frontend. How am I able to display it in twig?

Comment: debug that your variable array have value as `{{ dump(dataPP_ids) }}`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, done and yes there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a trailing space here.

```
"plan_participate_id "
```

Instead of

```
"plan_participate_id"
```

You should either remove it or access it in twig like that.

```
{{ details['plan_participate_id '] }}
```

Comment: WTH. Maybe I'm too burnout. I did not notice that. Yes it now working. Thanks.